# How to use a variable as value of replace function in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have such dataframe where the column `body` has image path that I want to replace with the corresponding baseUrl + `id` + .webp

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': ["982951473","000590051"],
                    'body': ["<script type=""application/ld+json"">{""image"":""https:\/\/www.f.it\/media\/catalog\/product\/2\/4\/240297_1.jpg?optimize=medium&fit=bounds&height=265&width=265&canvas=265:265"",""sku"":""982951473""}</script>","<script type=""application/ld+json"">{""image"":""https:\/\/www.f.it\/media\/catalog\/product\/0\/0\/000590051_rinazina_spray.jpg?optimize=medium&fit=bounds&height=265&width=265&canvas=265:265"",""sku"":""000590051""}</script>"]})

var = "f.com\/" + df['id'] + ".webp"
df_r = df.replace(to_replace=r'www[.]f[.]it[\\].*?["]', value=var, regex=True)

print(df_r.to_string())
```

At the end of the day this example url

```
""https:\/\/www.f.it\/media\/catalog\/product\/2\/4\/240297_1.jpg?optimize=medium&fit=bounds&height=265&width=265&canvas=265:265""
```

Should become this url which contain the id variable

```
""https:\/\/f.com\/982951473.webp""
```

Comment: The doubled quotation marks (""..."") in the dataframe seem to be a problem, when I run this code the data in df have no quotation marks at all.

Comment: The answer provided by @phibel is correct and more applicable to other cases, so I'd suggest using that instead. But a small change to your code that would provide the same results would be to extend your regexes in order to match the `id` in the body: `df_r = df.replace(to_replace=r'www[.]f[.]it[\\].*?["],"sku":"(\d+)"', value=r'f.com\/\1.webp,"sku":"\1"', regex=True)` This supposes that your body always has the "sku" part.

Comment: Hi @phibel the doubled quotation marks `""` found in data files are to preserve double quotes so this `""` means this `"` and that avoid also conflicts with single quotation mark `'` wrongly used in text by the end user content

Comment: Ok, but for your provided minimal example with only Python code it is not correct. Is my answer below ok for you?

Answer (score 1):

The first error was the double quotations in your provided DataFrame. In python `"...""sku"":""982951473""..."` is simply `sku:982951473` and not your expected `"sku":"982951473"`. I modified your provided DataFrame...

```
import pandas as pd
import re

REGEX_URL = re.compile(r'www[.]f[.]it\\.*?"')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['982951473', '000590051'],
    'body': [
        '<script type="application/ld+json">{"image":"https:\/\/www.f.it\/media\/catalog\/product\/2\/4\/240297_1.jpg?optimize=medium&fit=bounds&height=265&width=265&canvas=265:265","sku":"982951473"}</script>',
        '<script type="application/ld+json">{"image":"https:\/\/www.f.it\/media\/catalog\/product\/0\/0\/000590051_rinazina_spray.jpg?optimize=medium&fit=bounds&height=265&width=265&canvas=265:265","sku":"000590051"}</script>',
    ]
})

print(df.to_string())

def replaceUrl(id, body):
    rep = f'f.com\/{id}.webp"'
    return REGEX_URL.sub(rep, body)

df['body'] = df.apply(lambda x: replaceUrl(x.id, x.body), axis=1)

print(df.to_string())
```

Or this way, I have no idea which is the better/faster approach.

```
for i, row, in df.iterrows():
    rep = f'f.com\/{df.at[i, "id"]}.webp"'
    df.at[i, 'body'] = REGEX_URL.sub(rep, row['body'])
```

output:

```
          id  body
0  982951473  <script type="application/ld+json">{"image":"https:\/\/www.f.it\/media\/catalog\/product\/2\/4\/240297_1.jpg?optimize=medium&fit=bounds&height=265&width=265&canvas=265:265","sku":"982951473"}</script>
1  000590051  <script type="application/ld+json">{"image":"https:\/\/www.f.it\/media\/catalog\/product\/0\/0\/000590051_rinazina_spray.jpg?optimize=medium&fit=bounds&height=265&width=265&canvas=265:265","sku":"000590051"}</script>
          id  body
0  982951473  <script type="application/ld+json">{"image":"https:\/\/f.com\/982951473.webp","sku":"982951473"}</script>
1  000590051  <script type="application/ld+json">{"image":"https:\/\/f.com\/000590051.webp","sku":"000590051"}</script>
```